# Populating JComboBox with custom objects stored in an ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

I'm trying to populate a `JComboBox` with object names.  The objects are of Category type and are stored in an `ArrayList` (named `categoryList`) in the Category class.

Here is the content of the `Category` class:

```
public class Category {
    private static String catName;
    private static List<Category> categoryList;

    public static void addToCatList(String str)
    {
        Category cat = new Category();
        Category.setCatName(str);

        categoryList.add(cat);
    }

    public static List<Category> getCatList()
    {
        return categoryList;
    }

    public static String getCatName() 
    {
        return catName;
    }

    public static void setCatName(String catName) 
    {
        Category.catName = catName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return catName;
    }
}
```

Here is the code that populates the `JCombobox` (method name: `populateComboBox()`):

```
        List<Category> catList = new ArrayList<Category>();
        catList = Category.getCatList();
        Category list[] = new Category[catList.size()];
        list = catList.toArray(list);

        for(int i = 0; i <list.length; i++)
        {    
            selectCatComboBox.addItem(list[i].getCatName());
         }
        addItemDialog.setVisible(true);
```

When I populate the `ArrayList` with 2 objects, named `Obj1` and `Obj2`, I get the following problems:

1. When `populateComboBox()` is invoked, the combo box only displays the second object i.e. it only displays `Obj2`.  The expected display was `Obj1`, `Obj2`.
2. Since it only displays `Obj2`. When `populateComboBox()` is invoked twice, the combo box displays two `Obj2`. When invoked three times it displays three `Obj2`. i.e. the number of times the method gets invoked, the number of times `Obj2` gets displayed in the combo box.
3. Should the `categoryList` `ArrayList` be inside the `Category` class? or should it be inside the control class? I'm a bit confused with this one.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson  Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your design is broken. Category's catName name field is static and so only one object exists **for the entire class**. If you change it, you change it class wide. This is why Obj1 and Obj2 (bad names for variables by the way) share the same name and display the same name.

This class should be broken into two classes, one say called Category that has no static fields, no List fields, has private instance fields, constructor(s), public methods, and another, perhaps called Categories, that holds a non-static `ArrayList<Category>`, with the `addCategory(...)` and such methods. Fix this first before concerning yourself with GUI, else you'll be building your house on a very shaky foundation. Whenever you create a static field, always ask yourself why you're doing this, and strongly consider seeing if you can make it instance instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the editing too!
You've cleared my doubts regarding where I should store my ArrayList (3). I've made the changes you've said. I've got a method called `getCatList()` in my `Categories` class (where the ArrayList has been stored), I was wondering if I should make this static..

Comment: @D.R.: at this point, your main method should be static, and that's about it.

Comment: I made the changes you've said, however I still get the problem no2. if I add two objects (lets name it `Obj1` and `Obj2`) to `ArrayList` and invoke the `populateComboBox()` method twice.  my output is `Obj1` `Obj2` `Obj1` `Obj2` instead of `Obj1` `Obj2`

Comment: @D.R.: then update the question adding the new code and explanation below the current code. Best if your code is a valid [sscce](http://sscce.org) (please check out the link).

Answer (score 1):

First off, I wouldn't have a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) that contains a List of itself. Also, the key word "static" means you can have only one of the variable across all instances of an object.

```
public class Category {
    private String name = null; // I always like to initialize my variables

    public Category() {
        // empty constructor method, but I like to have a no argument constructor
    }

    public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return catName;
    }
}

List<Category> catList = new ArrayList<>();
catList.add(new Category("Category 1"));
catList.add(new Category("Category 2"));

for (Category category : catList) {
    selectCatComboBox.addItem(category.getName());
}
addItemDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.